# Xinput device disable doesn't work for all mouses

Tags: ubuntu, xinput

There are 2 mouses connected to one computer and I want to disable them. I tried to do it using xinput. It works for one mouse (OM), but it doesn't for second (SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse). Second mouse is disabled only for a moment and after about minute it works again. Both mouses are on USB. I checked it on 3 different computers and it acts the same (ubuntu 12.04).

Is there other way to disable mouse for lets say 2 hours and then turn it on again?

```
adm@l:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse                       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ OM                                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Keyboard            id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
adm@l:~$ xinput set-prop 9 "Device Enabled" 0
adm@l:~$ xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

Adding `xorg.conf` into `/etc/X11` helped.

Now disabling mouses works forever, but after plugging new mouse or keyboard you have to enable it manually with `xinput`.

```
$ cat xorg.conf

Section "ServerFlags"
        Option  "AutoAddDevices"        "true"
        Option  "AutoEnableDevices"     "false"
        Option  "AllowMouseOpenFail"    "false"
        Option  "AllowEmptyInput"       "on"
EndSection
```